# AutoLock in Java - how to?

Tags: java, synchronization, locking

What is the best way to free resources (in this case unlock the ReadWriteLock) when leaving the scope ? How to cover all possible ways (return, break, exceptions etc)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A try/finally block is the closest thing that you can get to this behaviour:

```
Lock l = new Lock();
l.lock();  // Call the lock before calling try.
try {
    // Do some processing.
    // All code must go in here including break, return etc.
    return something;
} finally {
    l.unlock();
}
```

Comment: "l.lock()" should really be called before "try" as per the example: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

Comment: And to justify the prior comment:  the reason you want to call l.lock() outside the try block is that lock() may throw an exception - and if it does, you definitely don't want to call unlock() on it (which will then throw an exception and make it hard to find the original exception throw).

Answer (score 2):

Like mike said, a finally block should be your choice. see the [finally block tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html), where it is stated:

> The finally block **always** executes when
>   the try block exits. This ensures that
>   the finally block is executed even if
>   an unexpected exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

A nicer way to do it is to use the try-with-resources statement, which lets you mimick C++'s [RAII mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization):

```
public class MutexTests {

    static class Autolock implements AutoCloseable {
        Autolock(ReentrantLock lock) {
            this.mLock = lock;
            mLock.lock();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            mLock.unlock();
        }

        private final ReentrantLock mLock;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        try (Autolock alock = new Autolock(lock)) {
            // Whatever you need to do while you own the lock
        }
        // Here, you have already released the lock, regardless of exceptions

    }

}
```